Not parser-inserted case of preparation scripts
Spec has in algorithm of prepare the script element the following case:

3.3.2 is a loop that executes all the script elements of list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible and which have been initialized (of course, this is not parser-inserted).
Understanding these steps wouldn't be a problem if step 3.3 didn't store substeps for each script element and didn't perform them after fetching.
All substeps 3.3 will be performed as part of fetching the script.
What kind of case is this in which, when inserting, for example, two scripts into a document, this cycle (3.3.2) will make sense (that is, execution will be for more than one element)?
